# Bootstrap multiselect event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, bootstrap-multiselect

In a page I have three bootstrap multiselects. I've seen in the documentation that an event "onDropdownHide" exists and that the normal way to assign a function to it is something like this:

```
$("#multiselect").multiselect(
    onDropdownHide: function() {
    }
);
```

The reason I don't want to make it like this, is that all the other parameters I use are the same, so I have something like this:

```
var attr = { param1: val1, param2: val2, ...};
$("#multiselect1").multiselect(attr);
$("#multiselect2").multiselect(attr);
$("#multiselect3").multiselect(attr);
```

But the function I need to call in each case is different, so I'm trying to not redefine the same array for only one parameter. I'm trying to make something like:

```
var attr = { param1: val1, param2: val2, ...};
attr["onDropdownHide"] = function1;
$("#multiselect1").multiselect(attr);
attr["onDropdownHide"] = function2;
$("#multiselect2").multiselect(attr);
attr["onDropdownHide"] = function3;
$("#multiselect3").multiselect(attr);
```

But I can't find a way to make it work.

Comment: You can loop through your dom-id array and run the same function for different ids. Or you can create a function and pass that to all others. If you could share  some minimal reproducible example then it will be helpful.

Comment: An example of the problem with codepen.io or jsfiddle.net would help out a lot. I'm not quite understanding the issue myself.